# Ruby DataMapper save from model

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I try to save some data frome the model object, but nothing happens :(
What I do not right?

```rb
class Gallery
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :title, String
  property :user, String
  property :album, String
  property :place, String
  property :fotki, Text
  property :date, Date
  property :created_at, DateTime

  default_scope(:default).update(:order => [:created_at.desc])

  def get_images
    if @fotki.nil? then
      fotki = Fotki.get(@user, @album)
      self.update(:fotki => fotki.to_json)
      puts 'Request'
      fotki
    else
      puts 'Use Cache'
      JSON.parse(@fotki)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It's not clear from reading your code.  I don't believe `update` accepts an `:order` like that, since it's not a select query, it's an update.  That aside, you should never try to write data from directly inside the body of the class like that. Add a method and invoke it explicitly. That code will run whenever the class happens to get loaded into memory, which is bad.

Comment: I use external service to store photos. And use it's API to get photos URLs specified for :user and :album number. Then I get it I want to cache data in database instead of new request in future. I invoke like that gallery = Gallery.get(params[:id]); photos = gallery.get_images

Comment: What does `gallery.errors` contain?  There was some confusion on my part when I made my first comment, regarding what the `default_scope` call was for. It's not a very clear interface, but that's DM anyway.  I've learnt something now!

Comment: Nothing :( pry(#<Gallery>)> errors
=> #<DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors:0x00000001b0f918
 @errors={},

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in datamapper that can cause the following situartion:

```
resource = SomeModel.new(attributes_from_somewhere)
resource.valid? # => true
resource.save   # => false, and no db interaction
resource.saved? # => false
```

A valid resource that could not be saved. A silent failure.

This silent failure problem could be solved with using the `raise_on_save_failre` setting. But the exception message was still meaningless. Only talking about #save returned with false ;).

The problem occurs where values that are not valid for a specific property are being persisted. For example a boolean or a uncoerced string in the `date` property.

With the [fix](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/commit/8785fbe01a36f6b2bd5e32317bdd085e0147b433) datamapper will raise a meaningful exception when about to persist an invalid value for a property. Sadly there is currently no release that contains the fix. You'll have to try the master branch from https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core!

Disclaimer: Im the author of the fix.